# How to display two columns and two rows in mobile using bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap 5. I have to show 2 columns and 2 rows on my mobile but its displaying the 1 row.

I have 2 psds like this in desktop

[image]

And in mobile

[image]

What should I do with Bootstrap 5, it should be 6 columns in desktop mode and 2 columns in mobile mode, and also in mobile mode, which is 2 columns, display it with horizontal scrolling for others.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="content">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-6 mb-3 text-center">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-circle"></i>
            <h5>عمومی</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-6 mb-3 text-center">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-circle"></i>
            <h5>دندان</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-6 mb-3 text-center">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-circle"></i>
            <h5>رادیولوژی</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-6 mb-3 text-center">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-circle"></i>
            <h5>عصبی</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-6 mb-3 text-center">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-circle"></i>
            <h5>چشم</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-6 mb-3 text-center">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-circle"></i>
            <h5>عصبی</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-6 mb-3 text-center">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-circle"></i>
            <h5>تغذیه</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-6 mb-3 text-center">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-circle"></i>
            <h5>عصبی</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-6 mb-3 text-center">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-circle"></i>
            <h5>رادیولوژی</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-6 mb-3 text-center">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-circle"></i>
            <h5>اطفال</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-6 mb-3 text-center">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-circle"></i>
            <h5>عصبی</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-6 mb-3 text-center">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-circle"></i>
            <h5>همه</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's already meeting your columns requirement. Isn't?

Comment: Yes, it meets my column needs for now.

My problem should be shown in the 2-row mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card custom-card">
                <div class="card-body">

                    Card 1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card custom-card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    
                    Card 2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card custom-card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    
                    Card 3
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card custom-card">
                <div class="card-body">
                   
                    Card 4
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can you try this